# Casting a reflected object to another type with a GenericTypeArgument during runtime

Tags: c#, entity-framework, generics, reflection, casting

Situation:

Using Asp.net Core(2.1) and EFCore(2.1)

In an api controller I get a string of a type and need to get a working Iqueryable from this.

I can get something from this through reflection on the dbcontext, which has all the objects I would need as `DbSet<Type>`, which I then do `AsQueryable()` on.

Problem is that the only way to get the Correct DbSet from the context is through reflection. But this only return an object of type Object.

I don't know any way to cast this object back to it's `DbSet<Type>` during runtime and I was wondering if someone else knew of it.

Comment: The is a mapping that exists between a dataset/datatable and the database (dbcontext). See msdn : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.mapping.mappingitemcollection(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @jdweng I'm using EFCore, and I don't see this available there or something similar. Would probably be useful if it was. I'll add EFCore to the question.

Comment: The information is only available at runtime, how should the compiler know what to cast?